# Difference between FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext and FormatDateTime

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to display Date only not time.

when I edit XSL file, I see below function :

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext(string(@pro-date))" />
```

I am confuse which one from below to use to show only date?

`ddwrt:FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext(string(@pro-date))`

OR

`ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@ActivityDate, 1033, 'MM/dd/yyyy')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FormatDateTimeUsingCurrentContext** is used to format the field value with the default DateTime format setting of the current SharePoint server context.

As you can see, it only passes field value parameter as a string , no need to additional parameter like 'dd/MM/yy' because it should format this value as the default current settings ,

**In case of**, you need to customize this default format for a specific field so you should use

```
FormatDate(string szDate, long lcid, long formatFlag);
```

where `formatFlag` is the format of the displayed date as mentioned in this table

Eg: `FormatDate(@Field, 1033, 1)` should return **9/28/2016**

[image]

Or use

```
FormatDateTime(string szDate, long lcid, string szFormat);
```

where `szFormat` is 'dd/MM/yyyy' represent **28/09/2016**